# Manually Triggering Alerts for Simulated Devices

Tags: azure, azure-iot-central

is there anyway we can manually trigger an alert for a simulated device instead of waiting for its value to trigger it? e.g. manually setting the value of the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update a setting to achieve this purpose. In Azure IoT Central portal you can edit a setting and update it like this:

[image]

After you click update button the device will receive a DesiredPropertyUpdate callback. In that callback you can configure the device takes an action. To complete this you need set the callback handler:

```
Client.SetDesiredPropertyUpdateCallbackAsync(HandleSettingChanged, null).Wait();
```

And the handler like this, for example:

```
    private static async Task HandleSettingChanged(TwinCollection desiredProperties, object userContext)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received settings change...");
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(desiredProperties));

            string setting = "fanSpeed";
            if (desiredProperties.Contains(setting))
            {
                // Act on setting change, then
                AcknowledgeSettingChange(desiredProperties, setting);
            }
            await Client.UpdateReportedPropertiesAsync(reportedProperties);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Error in sample: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

For detailed information, you can reference this tutorial: "[Connect a Raspberry Pi to your Azure IoT Central application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/howto-connect-raspberry-pi-csharp)".